# SSRS 2016 Custom Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have an mvc app that builds the report from the report server it reads the content via a stream. Now what I am required to do is create a CustomAuthentication for SSRS2016 so that I may automatically login as a guest user (credentials are saved in config, for now). Every link that explains the "how to" of CustomAuthentication they have a login page.

Am I required to create that ??

I know I should user IAuthenticationExtension but I don't want the user to login into the server nor do I have a database that contains the username and password as most sources use such a db.

If I'm not required to create a page what is the alternative to the traditional LogonUser(string userName, string password, string auth) ?

Answer (score 1):

See if this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3e11282-495b-4e2a-b422-524dba378444/custom-authentication-provider-for-ssrs-2016-?forum=SQLServer2016Preview) helps.
Or try something like this.

```
internal class ReportCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
    {
        private string strUserName;
        private string strPassword;
        private string strDomain;

        public ReportCredentials(string strUserName, string strPassword, string strDomain)
        {
            this.strUserName = strUserName;
            this.strPassword = strPassword;
            this.strDomain = strDomain;
        }
        public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
        {
            get { return new NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword, strDomain); }
        }

        public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user,
         out string password, out string authority)
        {
            authCookie = null;
            user = password = authority = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and this

```
string strUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"].ToString();
string strPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString();
string strDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain"].ToString();

ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportCredentials(strUserName, strPassword, strDomain);
```